# Gradle's com.moowork.gradle.grunt plugin

Tags: gradle, gruntjs, build-process

I have a webapp compilation subproject which is written in a separate script plugin and is being added to the root project via "apply from: scriptSrc" syntax. Top of my script plugin looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.moowork.grunt"
```

However its not recognizing the plugin and fails on the initialization phase saying

```
Plugin with id 'com.moowork.grunt' not found.
```

I am following this: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.grunt/0.10. 
Anyone else having issues with grunt plugin inclusion in script plugin?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue as it works just fine for me. Though you should keep in mind that the repository url for the plugin portal is not the  jcenter repository. Here it seems to work as the plugin author published his plugin to both repositories

Comment: @ReneGroeschke you are right about the repo url. I tried it with both and dependency gets downloaded fine. The problem is gradle is unable to recognize the plugin by id 'com.moowork.grunt' in my script plugin. Can you please confirm it you tried to repro this inside script plugin and not the main buildscript?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what exactly is causing the issue. Make sure you have the buildscript setup the following way.

```
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.grunt'
buildscript{
     dependencies{
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.13'
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.12'
    }

    // In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
    repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
    }   
}
```

If you go plan to use plugin:0.13, you need to include the node-plugin as well or else you may get a NoClassDefFound Exception. This may not be necessary if you continue to use version 0.10.

Also, if you are working on a gradle project in eclipse and building the project from commandline, make sure you refresh the project so build reflects in your workspace.